# onLogin() function not being called

Tags: android-simple-facebook

We're using the same procedure and code given in gitHub, but the function onLogin() in the onLoginListener is not being called, because of which we can't proceed. We're doing everything as mentioned, but still the onLogin function is not working. Following is the code we're using for reference from: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

```
enter code here
import com.sromku.simple.fb.Permission;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.SessionManager.SessionStatusCallback;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebookConfiguration;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.listeners.OnLoginListener;

.
.
.
.

OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {
@Override
public void onLogin() {
    // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
    Log.i(TAG, "Logged in");
}
```

Comment: do you call `simpleFacebook.login()`?

Comment: we were able to resolve the issue, some problem was there with our Facebook app for android.